# How to write this underdash?

Tags: nesting

I want to write this expression :
[image]
so, what will be its code? please help...

Comment: `\underline{100101}` or what do you mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved via comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\underline` macro allows you to underline a word in a sentence. If you want to underline a sentence, the `ulem` package allows you to underline a sentence written on **several** lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\textbf{With underline}:

\underline{100101} 101

\bigskip

\textbf{with uline}:

%allows you to underline a sentence written on several lines
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
   \uline{allows you to underline a sentence written on several lines}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.9\textwidth}
  % \uline{100101} 101
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't think he needs to underline multi-line text though. He only needs to underline `100101`.

Comment: As marmot said "*The point of answers is to go beyond what already existed before*"