# Linebreaks in formated texts

Tags: formatting, subscripts, underline

I need to format my **text in bold** therefore I have several options for the same result. The main result would look like

`\textbf{text in bold}`

which works fine. But as soon as line breaks start to kick in the problem seems to get difficult. E.g.

```
\textbf{text

in bold}
```

Especially with the additional line break in between. LaTeX fails to compile. The log files indicate an introduced `\par` which seems to be in conflict with `\textbf`.

I found the solution for replace `\textbf` with `{\bfseries ...}`. Other solutions I found are  italic (=`{\itshape...}`, `\texttt` (=`{\ttfamily...}`)

I have the same problems for

- `\underline`,
- `\textsubscript` and
- `\textsuperscript`

are there similar *solutions* as for the bold font available?

Comment: As for the `\underline`, have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478019/156344). I am wondering why you want to use subscript and superscript multiline.

Comment: All of the commands you mention are intended for use with small sections of text *within* a paragraph.  If you want multiple paragraphs with a different font, size, marking, etc, then you should probably define a new _environment_ that changes the text as you want it.

Comment: See (for example)  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/15036

Comment: @JouleV: Sorry but the approach for `\underline` has exactly the same result.
@Thruston: I don't understand how to define a new environment. Just defining `\newenvironment{myUL}[1]{\underline{#1}}{\par}` will only format the very first char. And for the definition of a font: I want to use the regular font - just with e.g. `underline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ul` from soul accepts arguments with a `\par`/empty line in it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

\ul{text 

 text}
\end{document}
```

`\par` in `\textsuperscript` is imho senseless.

Comment: Thx - I'll test it tomorrow. I can somehow agree with your comment about the _senseless_ par in ˋsuperscriptˋ. The problem is that the compiler ends with an error - ie. doesn't skip the _senseless_ part. Its more about a valid TeX code than a _meaningful_ code - Although I highly appreciate if it would work.

Comment: So  more or less the q remains: is there a way to avoid the error - for these special (corner) cases? e.g. tell LaTeX to ignore all linebreaks within e.g. ˋ\textsuperscriptˋ

Comment: Yes, you can make all definitions long. But the reason that they are not is to get errors, if you forget a closing brace. Without it something like `\textbf{some text` will read your complete document while searching the end of the argument.

Comment: Yeah, but how to do it practically?

Comment: Well you look at the code and replace in all needed places \def by \long\def and similar. And as tests can change if a definition is suddenly long you should check for this too.

Comment: Is there somewhere a description available for ˋ\longˋ. I searched but didn't find any :-/

Comment: That's a tex primitive. Check the texbook or tex by topic.